# unable to upgrade or download from ubuntu software center or appgrid

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center, dpkg

I am new to linux. 
Recently I installed barry desktop a client for blackberry sync.And after reboot I found an error notification on the desktop panel with an error message saying

```
ERROR: BROKEN COUNT>0"[the error notification I get on my desktop][1]
```

When I use the updater to update I get the following error message:

```
[updater error message][2]
"The package system is broken:
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f"
```

I am also not able to install anything from the software centre or from Appgrid either. I get the following error message on opening the software center:

```
[error message on opening software center][3]

"New software cannot be installed because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?".
When I click "repair", the operation fails with another error message as follows:[package operation failed error message][4]

"PACKAGE OPERATION FAILED
The installation or removal of a software package failed
detail:
 installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 265674 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../barry-util_0.18.5-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking barry-util (0.18.5-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/barry-util_0.18.5-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/bash_completion.d/bjavaloader', which is also in package linberry 1.1b1a
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/barry-util_0.18.5-1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of barrydesktop:
 barrydesktop depends on barry-util; however:
  Package barry-util is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package barrydesktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

SAME ERROR AS ABOVE WHEN I TRY TO INSTALL FROM APPGRID. 
I believe I started having this trouble since I installed BARRY DESKTOP a client for blackberry sync.
Please kindly help me with this. Thankyou.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` as suggested in the error message ? Not working ? Any errors ?

Comment: @markkirby yea I tried. It didnt help. Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/barry-util_0.18.5-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: no idea what it means!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this solution worked for me: 
http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/184249#.V1K85kqLRNw

```
sudo su
mv  /var/lib/dpkg/status  /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old  /var/lib/dpkg/status
mv /var/lib/dpkg/available  /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old  /var/lib/dpkg/available
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Hope it works also for you.